# How should i update the id of the nodes in the 2D array in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, redux

Hey i have been developing a program where the user can add or delete the nodes at any index value in the 2D array but the thing is, i m getting only the clicked element index not all of them, so how should i manipulate the ID's of this 2D array.

```js
click = (row, col ) => {
    console.log("click fun",row, col);
    // alert(window.event.clientX)
    IDIS = `${row}${col}`;
    // IDIS = window.event.clientX*window.event.clientY;
    console.log("row ,col ", row, col);
    console.log("dontTriggerClick", dontTriggerClick);
    if (dontTriggerClick) {
      dontTriggerClick = false;
      return;
    }
    var { logic } = this.props;

    console.log("logic", this.props);

    const { currentProgramGuide } = logic;

    var todo = "current";

    logic.insertState = false;

    const { type } = drawing.board[row][col];

    console.log("type", type);

    if (type === "blank" || type === "hand" || type === "highlighted_hand")
      todo = "blank";
    if (todo === "current") {
      logic.active = [row, col];

      console.log("click current");

      drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
        logic.program,
        logic.end,
        logic.currentProgramGuide,
        logic.active,
        this.add,
        logic.insertState,
        this.insertNode,
        this.deleteNode
      );
      var logicState = {};
      // logicState['type'] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
      // logicState['state'] = logic;
      console.log("NOW ZOOM  3", this.props);
        // IDIS=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000000)
      // idss.push(`${row}-${col}`);
      //  logic.ids=idss;


      this.props.update(logic);
    } else if (todo === "blank") {
      console.log("clickfun blank");
      console.log("[-1, -1]");
      logic.active = [-1, -1];

      // Uncomment the following line to auto-minimize bottomPanel on blank space click
      // logic.bottomPanel = 'border';
      drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
        logic.program,
        logic.end,
        logic.currentProgramGuide,
        logic.active,
        this.add,
        logic.insertState,
        this.insertNode,
        this.deleteNode
      );
      var logicState = {};
      logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
      logicState["state"] = logic;
      console.log("NOW ZOOM  4", this.props);

      this.props.update(logic);
    }
  };
  recurseAdd = (instructions, nesting, toPush) => {
    console.log("i am recurseAdd");

    console.log(
      "instructions11 new ",
      typeof instructions,
      instructions,

      nesting - 1,
      toPush
    );
    if (instructions.length !== 0) {
      if (nesting === 0) {
        console.log("IF CONDIOTION recurseAdd");
        instructions.push(toPush);
      } else {
        console.log("ELSE CONDIOTION recurseAdd");
        this.recurseAdd(
          instructions[instructions.length - 1].subprogram,
          nesting - 1,
          toPush
        );
      }

      console.log(
        "END recurseAdd",
        instructions.length !== 0,
        typeof instructions,
        instructions,
        nesting - 1,
        toPush
      );
    }
  };
  add = (type) => {
    console.log("add fun");

    console.log("add fun type", type);
    if (type == "repeat") {
      this.setState({ readyForSimulation: type });
      sessionStorage.setItem("programEnd", type);
    }

    if (dontTriggerClick) {
      console.log("dontTriggerClick");
      dontTriggerClick = false;
      return;
    }

    var { logic } = this.props;

    logic.active = [-1, -1];

    console.log("ANKIT 222", type);

    // console.log("logic.program new", logic.program, type)

    if (
      type === "end_variable" ||
      type === "end_sensor" ||
      type === "end_condition" ||
      type === "end_if" ||
      type === "end_loop" ||
      type === "repeat"
    )
      logic.currentProgramGuide--;
    else {
      var toPush = { type: type, state: {} };

      console.log("logic.program", logic.program);
      console.log("logic.currentProgramGuide", logic.currentProgramGuide);
      console.log("toPush", toPush);

      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        toPush.subprogram = [];
      this.recurseAdd(logic.program, logic.currentProgramGuide, toPush);
      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        logic.currentProgramGuide++;
    }

    console.log("addfun, ");

    console.log(
      "addfun : logic.currentProgramGuide ",
      logic.currentProgramGuide
    );

    console.log("addfun :  logic.active, ", logic.active);

    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;
    console.log("NOW ZOOM  5", this.props);

    this.props.update(logic);
  };
  insertNode = (type) => {
    // console.log("insertNode", drawing.activeParentRef[drawing.activeIndex]);
    // for(let n = 0; n<drawing.activeParentRef.slice(drawing.activeIndex, drawing.activeParentRef.length).length; n++){
    //   drawing.activeParentRef[n].id= JSON.stringify(Number(drawing.activeParentRef[n].id) + 1) 
    // }
    // console.log("new drawing.activeParentRef[i]type", type)
    console.log("ANKIT 333", type);
    num++;

    var { logic } = this.props;
    if (!logic.insertState){
      logic.insertState = true;
    } else {
      logic.insertState = false;
      var temp = drawing.activeParentRef[drawing.activeIndex];

      var toPush = { type: type, state: {}, id: IDIS};
      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        toPush.subprogram = [];
      drawing.activeParentRef[drawing.activeIndex] = toPush;
      for (
        let i = drawing.activeIndex + 1;
        i < drawing.activeParentRef.length;
        i++
      ) {
        var temp2 = drawing.activeParentRef[i];
        drawing.activeParentRef[i] = temp;
        temp = temp2;
      }
      if (temp) drawing.activeParentRef.push(temp);
      logic.active = [-1, -1];
    }
    console.log("logic.program", logic.program);
    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add,
      logic.insertState,
      this.insertNode,
      this.deleteNode
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;
    console.log("NOW ZOOM  6", this.props);

    this.props.update(logic);
    this.onUpdate()
  };

  deleteNode = () => {
    console.log("deleteNode");
    var { logic } = this.props;
    if (
      drawing.activeParentRef.length - 1 == drawing.activeIndex &&
      (drawing.activeRef.type === "variable" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "sensor" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "condition" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "loop")
    ) {
      let currentProgramGuide = 0,
        temp = logic.program;
      while (
        temp != drawing.activeParentRef &&
        currentProgramGuide < logic.currentProgramGuide
      ) {
        temp = temp[temp.length - 1].subprogram;
        currentProgramGuide++;
      }
      if (currentProgramGuide < logic.currentProgramGuide)
        logic.currentProgramGuide = currentProgramGuide;
    }
    // alert(drawing.activeIndex)
    drawing.activeParentRef.splice(drawing.activeIndex, 1);
    logic.active = [-1, -1];

    console.log("deleteNode fun ");
    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add,
      logic.insertState,
      this.insertNode,
      this.deleteNode
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;
    console.log("NOW ZOOM  7", this.props);

    this.props.logicComponent(logic);
    this.onUpdate()
    console.log("777777777777",this.props.logic.program)
  };
```

Redux logic:

```js
case 'LOGIC_SELECTION':
            var { program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel } = payload
            var data = { ...state, program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel }
            // sessionStorage.setItem('logic', JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
```

I tried all the ways but i m getting problem in the 2D part means the array is coming like 1st line then the second line but i want to print it like the flow of the diagram in flowchart

Comment: Why are you using redux if you put all logic in the click handlers and then dispatch the updated state with the action?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your data structure looks like and why you posted what looks like overly complex code, if you have an issue you should post a minimal reproducible example.

So I ignore your code dump because SO is not a site for debugging your code, if you have questions about code design you could try [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Below is an example of an answer to your question:

> How should i update the id of the nodes in the 2D array in JS?

Using react and redux (tagged in your question)

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      children: [
        {
          id: 2,
          children: [{ id: 3, children: [] }],
        },
        { id: 4, children: [] },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
const REMOVE = 'REMOVE';
//action creators
const add = (item) => ({
  type: ADD,
  payload: item,
});
const remove = (item) => ({
  type: REMOVE,
  payload: item,
});
const getId = ((id) => () => id++)(5);
const recursiveAdd = (path, items) => {
  const recur = (path) => (item) => {
    if (item.id === path[0] && path.length === 1) {
      return {
        ...item,
        children: item.children.concat({
          id: getId(),
          children: [],
        }),
      };
    }
    if (item.id !== path[0]) {
      return item;
    }
    return {
      ...item,
      children: item.children.map(recur(path.slice(1))),
    };
  };
  return items.map(recur(path));
};
const recursiveRemove = (path, items) => {
  const ID = {};
  const recur = (path) => (item) => {
    if (item.id === path[0] && path.length === 2) {
      return {
        ...item,
        children: item.children.filter(
          ({ id }) => id !== path[1]
        ),
      };
    }
    if (item.id !== path[0]) {
      return item;
    }
    return {
      ...item,
      children: item.children.map(recur(path.slice(1))),
    };
  };
  return recur([ID].concat(path))({
    id: ID,
    children: items,
  }).children;
};
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return {
      ...state,
      items: recursiveAdd(payload, state.items),
    };
  }
  if (type === REMOVE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      items: recursiveRemove(payload, state.items),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const Item = React.memo(function ItemComponent({
  item,
  add,
  remove,
  path,
}) {
  const currentPath = path.concat(item.id);
  return (
    <li>
      {item.id}
      <button onClick={() => add(currentPath)}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={() => remove(currentPath)}>
        Remove
      </button>
      {item.children && Boolean(item.children.length) && (
        <ul>
          {item.children.map((child) => (
            <Item
              key={child.id}
              item={child}
              add={add}
              remove={remove}
              path={currentPath}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
});
const ROOT = [];
const App = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addItem = React.useCallback(
    (item) => dispatch(add(item)),
    [dispatch]
  );
  const removeItem = React.useCallback(
    (item) => dispatch(remove(item)),
    [dispatch]
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          add={addItem}
          remove={removeItem}
          path={ROOT}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```